# Async webresponse in controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asynchronous

I have an MVC controller. In that controller I reference a WCF service that accesses a 3rd party request (through webrequest) which returns information which is then saved in the WCf service (very specifically, we're collection data about visits and saving them into a database so that we can target our page organization better).

The TL;DR is like this:

```
 private ActionResult CollectTrackingData(string campaign = "none")
    {
        VanityURLService.VanityURLConnector connector = new VanityURLService.VanityURLConnector();
        connector.SaveTrackingData(Request, campaign); 
        return View(someVarView);
    }
```

The SaveTrackingData does a bunch of stuff until it calls this method (edited to protect the not-so-innocent):

```
 private string TranslateGeolocation(string ipAddress)
    {
        WebRequest pageRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://blahblah.com");
        WebResponse resp = pageRequest.GetResponse();

        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string reqResp = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        return reqResp.ToString();
    }
```

The part that is likely to cause problems is the `WebResponse resp = pageRequest.GetResponse();` but I can't help thinking that the best way to do that is to make the call that cascades the entire process asynchoronous (that would be the controller code: `connector.SaveTrackingData(Request, campaign);`

But when I try to make the call async, it whines at me about a few things until, after much tweaking, it demands that I have it return a return type and then still doesn't work because I supposedly can't make that asynchronous at that stage of the page life cycle (which it then offers aspx code which is useless since I'm running with a Razor engine).

This all seems like it's being way more difficult than it needs to be. I feel like I should be able to make the `CollectTrackingData()` call async but it doesn't like that.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your action method to return `Task<ActionResult>`.

Everything will then work fine.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult>'

Sorry, I've not worked with Task and async before so I'm not sure what the fix would be for that.

Comment: @MetalPhoenix: You also need to make it `async`.

Comment: It.... the Action or the method I'm calling inside the Task<ActionResult> action?

Comment: Everything that calls an async method.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your method to async, the correct method signature is:

```
private Task<string> TranslateGeolocation(string ipAddress)
```

Then to call it:

```
string str = await TranslateGeolocation(ipAddress);
```

The `await` keyword will unwrap the `string` from the`Task<>` for you.

If you were to want to convert a method that would normally not return a value, i.e.,

```
private void DoSomething()
```

the asynchronous signature would be:

```
private Task DoSomething()
```

Comment: string geoResp = await TranslateGeolocation("70.60.249.115");

returns the error:

Cannot await string. 

The issue with that though is that the database save command comes right after the TranslateGeolocation command so I imagine it would try to save before getting the results back. Therefore shouldn't the call to that (SaveTrackingData()) be called async instead? Hence the original problem of trying to call it async from the controller...

Comment: You said you tried to make it async, and it whines, and you tweak a few things but then get stuck. Can you update your question with the async code as far as you've gotten it? It would help me diagnose the problem from there.